# If WebElement in ArrayList dont display, how can i handle it and continue enumeration through the list? Selenium, Junit

Tags: java, selenium, arraylist, junit, autotest

I have a list of WebElements that I check for visibility, but if I don't have one element in page, the check fails, how do I keep checking, but at the same time return false, that there is an error in the method?

```
    public boolean blockElementsIsDisplay() {
        List<WebElement> blockElements = new ArrayList<>();
        fourBlockElements.add(list1);
        fourBlockElements.add(list2);
        fourBlockElements.add(list3);
        fourBlockElements.add(list1Description);
        fourBlockElements.add(list2Description);
        fourBlockElements.add(list3Description);
        for (WebElement element : blockElements)
            if (!element.isDisplayed()) {
                System.out.println(element.getAccessibleName() + element.getLocation());
                return false;
            }
        return true;
```

so if i remove "return false" in code, metod finish with true, but i dont need it
I need to check all elements, and return false, if 1 or more is dosent displayed (and write names and locations of this elements)

Answer (score 0):

It was simple -.-
Just adding boolean bool;
and change return false to bool = false
and return true to return bool

```
public boolean blockElementsIsDisplay() {
    boolean bool = true;
    List<WebElement> blockElements = new ArrayList<>();
    fourBlockElements.add(list1);
    fourBlockElements.add(list2);
    fourBlockElements.add(list3);
    fourBlockElements.add(list1Description);
    fourBlockElements.add(list2Description);
    fourBlockElements.add(list3Description);
    for (WebElement element : blockElements)
        if (!element.isDisplayed()) {
            System.out.println(element.getAccessibleName() + element.getLocation());
            bool = false;
        }
    return bool;
```